# jQuery Ajax call returns different id depending on dataType

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been smashing my head with this and it's probably just my inexperience on dealing with frontend and I couldn't find the right answer.

I am doing an ajax call to my php on wordpress like this:

```
jQuery.ajax(
                  {
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
                    async: true,
                    data: {
                             action: 'get_yacht_by_id',
                             yacht_id: yacht_id
                             },
                    success: function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                    }
                });
```

and this returns:

[return on json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDgB0.png)

when I change dataType to text it returns a different id for each object instead of ending with 400 they end with 613

[on datatype text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B12Ne.png)

I can work around it, but I was just wondering why it's happening and if I am doing something wrong, as it's the same response both times and values change.

Comment: It's a precision error due to too many digits for an integer:  `var x= { id: 3426033690000104613 }; console.log(x)`

Comment: Hi, it might be, but I also just realized that the correct ID on the server side is the one I receive with datatype="text" and ends with 613... So the JSON actually changes it to 400 for some reason

Comment: *for some reason* - because of precision error due to too many digits for an integer - in javascript.